# Why python has different types of bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have two variables, one is `b_d`, the other is `b_test_d`.

When I type `b_d` in the console, it shows:

```
b'\\\x8f\xc2\xf5(\\\xf3?Nb\x10X9\xb4\x07@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
```

when I type `b_test_d` in the console, it shows:

```
b'[-2.1997713216,-1.4249271187,-1.1076795391,1.5224958034,-0.1709796203,0.3663875698,0.14846441,-0.7415930061,-1.7602231949,0.126605689,0.6010934792,-0.466415358,1.5675525816,1.00836295,1.4332792992,0.6113384254,-1.8008540571,-0.9443408896,1.0943670356,-1.0114642686,1.443892627,-0.2709427287,0.2990462512,0.4650133591,0.2560791327,0.2257600462,-2.4077429827,-0.0509983213,1.0062187148,0.4315075795,-0.6116110033,0.3495131413,-0.3249903375,0.3962305931,-0.1985757285,1.165792433,-1.1171953063,-0.1732557874,-0.3791600654,-0.2860519953,0.7872658859,0.217728374,-0.4715179983,-0.4539613811,-0.396353657,1.2326862425,-1.3548659354,1.6476230786,0.6312713442,-0.735444661,-0.6853447369,-0.8480631975,0.9538606574,0.6653542368,-0.2833696021,0.7281604648,-0.2843872095,0.1461980484,-2.3511731773,-0.3118047948,-1.6938613893,-0.0359659687,-0.5162134311,-2.2026641552,-0.7294895084,0.7493073213,0.1034096968,0.6439803068,-0.2596155272,0.5851323455,1.0173285542,-0.7370464113,1.0442954406,-0.5363832595,0.0117795359,0.2225617514,0.067571974,-0.9154681906,-0.293808596,1.3717113798,0.4919516922,-0.3254944005,1.6203744532,-0.1810222279,-0.6111596457,1.344064259,-0.4596893179,-0.2356197144,0.4529942046,1.6244603294,0.1849995925,0.6223061217,-0.0340662398,0.8365900535,-0.6804201929,0.0149665385,0.4132453788,0.7971962667,-1.9391525531,0.1440486871,-0.7103617816,0.9026539637,0.6665798363,-1.5885073458,1.4084493329,-1.397040825,1.6215697667,1.7057148522,0.3802647045,-0.4239271483,1.4773614536,1.6841461329,0.1166845529,-0.3268795898,-0.9612751672,0.4062399443,0.357209662,-0.2977362702,-0.3988147401,-0.1174652196,0.3350589818,-1.8800423584,0.0124169787,1.0015110265,0.789541751,-0.2710408983,1.4987300181,-1.1726824468,-0.355322591,0.6567978423,0.8319110558,0.8258835069,-1.1567887763,1.9568551122,1.5148655075,1.0589021915,-0.4388232953,-0.7451680183,-2.1897621693,0.4502135234,-1.9583089063,0.1358789518,-1.7585860897,0.452259777,0.7406800349,-1.3578980418,1.108740204,-1.1986272667,-1.0273598206,-1.8165822264,1.0853600894,-0.273943514,0.8589890805,1.3639094329,-0.6121993589,-0.0587067992,0.0798457584,1.0992814648,-1.0455733611,1.4780003064,0.5047157705,0.1565451605,0.9656886956,-0.5998330255,0.4846727299,0.8790524818,1.0288893846,-2.0842447397,0.4074607421,2.1523241756,-1.1268047125,-0.6016001524,-1.3302141561,1.1869516954,1.0988060125,0.7405900405,1.1813110811,0.8685330644,2.0927140519,-1.7171952009,0.9231993147,0.320874115,0.7465845079,-0.1034484959,-0.4776822499,0.436218328,-0.4083564542,0.4835567895,1.0733230373,-0.858658902,-0.4493571034,0.4506418221,1.6696649735,-0.9189799982,-1.1690356499,-1.0689397924,0.3174297583,1.0403701444,0.5440082812,-0.1128248996]'
```

Both of them are `bytes` type, but I can use `numpy.frombuffer` to read the `b_d`, but not the `b_test_d`. And they look very different. Why do I have these two types of bytes?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot use frombuffer on b_test_d. That's not very specific. What happens when you try?

Comment: And where did these two different variables come from?

Comment: Both are just `bytes` values. `frombuffer` imposes some additional constraints on the  subset of values it can *use*, but from a type perspective there is no difference between the two.

Comment: but why are the bytes represented differently?

Comment: They're not. The second one just happens to contain only values that can be represented directly as bytes.

Comment: I know it cannot be parsed by frombuffer -- obviously, they look very different. But the first question is why they are different?

Comment: That's entirely dependent on where the variables came from, which you don't include in your question.

Comment: They are different because they contain different content. The second one contains only characters that are representable in ASCII ("[", "-", "2", ",", etc). The first one contains a mix of ASCII characters ("?", "N", "b", etc) and other characters that have higher values.

Comment: But in fact, the original input of the first one is a numpy float array with all numeric elements. I use base64.b64encode(a) to encode it firstly. Then I do a_enc.decode('utf-8') to represent it as a string and send it. On the receiver side, I use base64.decode(a_enc.encode()) to parse the input. Eventually, I have the first one.

Comment: Oh, for the second one, I just learned that it was obtained by json marshal (convert a received float array to byte array, and then convert the result to base64 string, which is done by someone else). But the only thing I am curious is why they are different even both of them are bytes. (all original data is float array, but the result is so different).

Comment: The short answer is, they're different in the same way that `1` is different from `5`, even though they're both integers. They hold two entirely different values, the second one is just displayable using ASCII characters based on the byte values, as others have pointed out

Comment: Thanks, got it. But is there anyone can point out how to use Json marshall to convert the byte to the same type of bytes as the first one? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [A]nyone can point out how to use Json marshall to convert the byte to the same type of bytes as the first one?

This isn't the right question, but I think I know what you're asking. You say you're getting the 2nd array via JSON marshalling, but that it's also not under your control:

> it was obtained by json marshal (convert a received float array to byte array, and then convert the result to base64 string, which is done by someone else)

That's fine though, you just have to do a few steps of processing to get to a state equivalent to the first set of bytes.

---

First, some context to what's going on. You've already seen that `numpy` can understand your first set of bytes.

```
>>> numpy.frombuffer(data)
[1.21  2.963 1.   ]
```

Based on its output, it looks like `numpy` is interpreting your data as 3 doubles, with 8 bytes each (24 bytes total)...

```
>>> data = b'\\\x8f\xc2\xf5(\\\xf3?Nb\x10X9\xb4\x07@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
>>> len(data)
24
```

...which the `struct` module can also interpret.

```
# Separate into 3 doubles
x, y, z = data[:8], data[8:16], data[16:]
print([struct.unpack('d', i) for i in (x, y, z)])

[(1.21,), (2.963,), (1.0,)
```

---

There's actually (at least) 2 ways you can get a `numpy` array out of this.

### Short way

#### 1. Convert to string

```
# Original JSON data (snipped)
junk = b'[-2.1997713216,-1.4249271187,-1.1076795391,...]'
# Decode from bytes to a string (defaults to utf-8), then
# trim off the brackets (first and last characters in the string)
as_str = junk.decode()[1:-1]
```

#### 2. Use `numpy.fromstring`

```
numpy.fromstring(as_str, dtype=float, sep=',')

# Produces:
array([-2.19977132, -1.42492712, -1.10767954,  1.5224958 , -0.17097962,
        0.36638757,  0.14846441, -0.74159301, -1.76022319,  0.12660569,
        0.60109348, -0.46641536,  1.56755258,  1.00836295,  1.4332793 ,
        0.61133843, -1.80085406, -0.94434089,  1.09436704, -1.01146427,
        1.44389263, -0.27094273,  0.29904625,  0.46501336,  0.25607913,
        0.22576005, -2.40774298, -0.05099832,  1.00621871,  0.43150758,
        ... ])
```

### Long way

**Note**: I found the `fromstring` method after writing this part up, figured I'd leave it here to at least help explain the byte differences.

#### 1. Convert the JSON data into an array of numeric values.

```
# Original JSON data (snipped)
junk = b'[-2.1997713216,-1.4249271187,-1.1076795391,...]'
# Decode from bytes to a string - defaults to utf-8
junk = junk.decode()
# Trim off the brackets - First and last characters in the string
junk = junk[1:-1]
# Separate into values
junk = junk.split(',')
# Convert to numerical values
doubles = [float(val) for val in junk]

# Or, as a one-liner
doubles = [float(val) for val in junk.decode()[1:-1].split(',')]

# "doubles" currently holds:
[-2.1997713216,
 -1.4249271187,
 -1.1076795391,
 1.5224958034,
 ...]
```

#### 2. Use `struct` to get byte-representations for the doubles

```
import struct
as_bytes = [struct.pack('d', val) for val in doubles]

# "as_bytes" currently holds:
[b'\x08\x9b\xe7\xb4!\x99\x01\xc0',
 b'\x0b\x00\xe0`\x80\xcc\xf6\xbf',
 b'+ ..\x0e\xb9\xf1\xbf',
 b'hg>\x8f$\\\xf8?',
 ...]
```

#### 3. Join all the double values (as bytes) into a single byte-string, then submit to numpy

```
new_data = b''.join(as_bytes)
numpy.frombuffer(new_data)

# Produces:
array([-2.19977132, -1.42492712, -1.10767954,  1.5224958 , -0.17097962,
        0.36638757,  0.14846441, -0.74159301, -1.76022319,  0.12660569,
        0.60109348, -0.46641536,  1.56755258,  1.00836295,  1.4332793 ,
        0.61133843, -1.80085406, -0.94434089,  1.09436704, -1.01146427,
        1.44389263, -0.27094273,  0.29904625,  0.46501336,  0.25607913,
        0.22576005, -2.40774298, -0.05099832,  1.00621871,  0.43150758,
        ... ])
```

Answer (score 0):

A `bytes` object can be in any format.  It is "just a bunch of bytes" without context.  For display Python will represent byte values <128 as their ASCII value, and use hex escape codes (`\x##`) for others.

The first looks like IEEE 754 double precision floating point.  `numpy` or `struct` can read it.  The second one is in JSON format.  Use the `json` module to read it:

```
import numpy as np
import json
import struct

b1 = b'\\\x8f\xc2\xf5(\\\xf3?Nb\x10X9\xb4\x07@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
b2 = b'[-2.1997713216,-1.4249271187,-1.1076795391,1.5224958034]'

j = json.loads(b2)
n = np.frombuffer(b1)
s = struct.unpack('3d',b1)

print(j,n,s,sep='\n')

# To convert b2 into a b1 format
b = struct.pack('4d',*j)

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[-2.1997713216, -1.4249271187, -1.1076795391, 1.5224958034]
[1.21  2.963 1.   ]
(1.21, 2.963, 1.0)
b'\x08\x9b\xe7\xb4!\x99\x01\xc0\x0b\x00\xe0`\x80\xcc\xf6\xbf+ ..\x0e\xb9\xf1\xbfhg>\x8f$\\\xf8?'
```